# Detect if member has a role

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am building a Discord bot, more specific, a rolecolor command. I made a version of this command, that worked. Only problem was that it was extremly inefficient, it took like 5 minutes for it to respond. This was because there where a lot of 'if' statements and other things the bot had to check before executing anything. The file had 129K+ lines, and my whole editting program was lagging. I now have a new plan, that is probably much more efficient:

The bot checks if a member has any roles that start with "SRC -". SRC means server role color, just a name every role has that is dedicated to being cosmetic. All my colorrole names start with "SRC - *name*" If it detects any, delete them. Await this process, and after that, add the new color. I have like 205 roles for colors. I CAN just do:

```
 message.guild.members.cache
            .get(user.id)
            .roles.remove(roleone);
 message.guild.members.cache
            .get(user.id)
            .roles.remove(roletwo);
```

This works, but then again, inefficient. Discord isn't that fast with deleting and adding roles. When I ran a test, it didn't give me any errors. Despite this, I thought something was going wrong because my roles wheren't changing. When I was running a debug, and checked again, the roles where finally updated. It just takes a while before updating. I would like to have this more efficient. Here are some code samples:

Role adding, after the role removal:

```
if (args[0] === "1") {
            message.guild.members.cache
            .get(user.id)
            .roles.add(roleone);
            message.channel.send(errmsg);
            console.log(logmsg);
else if (args[0] === "2") //etc
```

So my question is, does someone know how to detect if the member has any roles that start with `name`, so that only those roles can be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.remove()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=remove) takes either a [`RoleResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/typedef/RoleResolvable), Array of `RoleResolvable`s, or a `Collection` of `RoleResolvable`s. You can filter the roles and pass it in

```js
const member = message.guild.members.resolve(user.id)
const roles = member.roles.cache.filter(r => r.name.startsWith(`SRC -`))
await member.roles.remove(roles) // remove all roles from the member that start with "SRC -"
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But do you also know how to count the amount of roles the bot has deleted? I tried `roles.length`, but that didn't work.

Comment: @PuffinKwadraat that would be `roles.size`